# Quill code block formatting

Tags: quill

In Quilljs editor code block are wrapped with . I'd like to use prismjs as code highlighter, but it requires to wrap code blocks in

```
<pre><code class='language-xxx'>...</code></pre>
```

I've been struggling to find a way to implement this for a couple of days now.
Is there a way to make quill use this structure instead of the default?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: First of all, one does not need the `<pre><code>` markup structure in order to use PrismJS - it is only a suggestion. Quill is internally hard-wired with Highlight.js. In order to use Prism.js, one has to overwrite a piece of code in Quills `Syntax` module. This is described here: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2130#issuecomment-494183592